# Ceiling that comes down in processing

Tags: processing

I need to implement a moving ceiling that descends every 10 seconds, similar to the iconic game "Puzzle Bubble." However, the ceiling currently appears and disappears almost instantly after the 10-second interval. I'm new to processing and I don't understand why does my grey rectangle, ceiling, appears and disappears immediately, after I called the function 'move_ceiling_down'!

To tackle this, I attempted to create a class called "Ceiling" in my implementation.

```
class Ceiling {
  float width, height,currentTime,intervalo, amount;
  Ceiling(float width, float height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.currentTime=0;
    this.intervalo=10000;
  }
  void draw() {
    fill(0);
    noStroke();
    rect(0, 0, 25, height);
    rect(width-25, 0, 25, height);
    rect(0, 0, width, 50);
    stroke(NORMAL);

    if (millis() - this.currentTime >= intervalo) {
      currentTime = millis();
      amount+=100;
      t1.move_ceiling_down(50,amount);
    }
  }

  void move_ceiling_down(float startY,float amount) {
    fill(125,125,125);
    noStroke();
    rect(0,startY,width,amount);
  }
}
```

My main:

```
import processing.sound.*;

SoundFile music;
Canon c1;
Ceiling t1;
float currentTime=0;
float intervalo = 10000;
float amount=0;


void setup() {
  background(255);
  size(550, 900);
  music = new SoundFile(this,"Musicadojogo.mp3");
  music.play();

  c1 = new Canon();
  t1 = new Ceiling(550,900);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  t1.draw();
  c1.draw();

  if (millis() - this.currentTime >= intervalo) {
    currentTime = millis();
    amount+=100;
    t1.draw().move_ceiling_down(50,amount);
    //c1.move_balls_down(amount);
  }

  println(mouseX,mouseY);
}

void keyPressed() {
  c1.keyPressed();
}
```

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Processing is a programming language: https://processing.org

Comment: @apodidae No, it's not; it's a library/framework. You can run processing in multiple languages, such as Java (the most popular), JS, or Python. However, one can assume OP is using Java here.

Comment: Quote from the Processing website: Processing is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code.   It does use java under the hood, but it is _not java and uses its own calls.  I think you unnecessarily closed this thread.

Comment: Please consider posting future questions to the Processing forum: https://discourse.processing.org . They won't close your thread.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the draw() method in the Ceiling class to display() to avoid confusion (Processing also uses the draw() method). Simplify the main draw() function to the following by removing the timer code; you already have timing code in the Ceiling class.  I commented out the Canon call since you didn't supply the code.

```
void draw() {
  t1.display();
 // c1.draw();
  println(mouseX,mouseY);
}
```